# IBM MobileFirst (MFP 8) weird behavior on isSuccessful response field

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

Our application have been running in production for about 6 months now. Suddenly we experience weird errors in our mobile app. We found out from the logs that there was a sudden change in the behavior of the response thrown by MFP.

Our MFP adapter interfaces to the app on one side, and connects to REST web services in the back end side.

Before, the behavior was like the one below. isSuccessful returns "true" even if HTTP status code returned from the REST web service was any other http code besides 200.

```
{  
   "statusCode":401,   
   "errors":[  

   ],
   "isSuccessful":true,
}
```

Now, if the status code is not 200, isSuccessful is showing false. We did not change anything in the MFP adapter code nor made any changes in MFP as well. This causes our application to behave in a different way than before.

```
{  
   "statusCode":401,   
   "errors":[  

   ],
   "isSuccessful":false,
}
```

Does anyone know the reason for this sudden change in behavior? we want to return the behavior as how it was before.

Comment: No changes at all? iFix updates? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile App will receive an 401 HTTP Status code whenever the user invokes an adapter endpoint with invalid Access token.

Check whether you have protected your Adapter Endpoint Custom OAuth Scope with any Security Check in Mobilefirst Operations Console.

If not, MFP SDK will handle this error and obtain's a fresh access token for default OAuth Scope and returns the adapter response.

Comment: the 401 was just an example. It behaves that way for all http status codes that are not 200